# How to check if value is in same "decade" as another value?

Tags: javascript, numbers, comparison

I get two values between 11 and 89 (without 20,30,40,etc) and need to check if the second is inside the same 10 as the first. Ej.:

```
var actual = 23;  
var next = 17;
```

Arent in same decade but:

```
var actual = 23;  
var next = 27;
```

are in same "decade".

How could I do this without spliting numbers?

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "splitting numbers"?

Comment: An idea I had was to split numbers and compare the first from each value.

Comment: Ah you mean convert them to strings and compare all but the last character. That would work, but it's simpler to do it numerically.

Comment: please add some more use cases.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant sorry, I'm not english. It's already solved thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide each number by 10, take the floor, and compare the result.

```
function sameDecade(n1, n2) {
  return Math.floor(n1 / 10) === Math.floor(n2 / 10);
}
```

So

```
if (sameDecade(actual, next)) {
  // actual and next are in the same decade
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked and it's a pretty simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to get a check if the delta is smaller than ten, you could check the absolute delta.

```js
const sameDecade = (a, b) => Math.abs(a - b) < 10;

console.log(sameDecade(23, 17));
console.log(sameDecade(23, 7));
console.log(sameDecade(10, 9));
console.log(sameDecade(23, 99));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just divide by `10` and check

```js
var actual = 23;  
var next = 27; 

console.log(Math.floor(actual / 10) === Math.floor(next/10))
```